# I can't get Ubuntu to download

Tags: installation, downloads

I haven't used Ubuntu for a few years so I thought I'd give it a try once more. I donated and then tried to download only to have it keep trying to connect - never allowing me to actually get the program. I even hit the "download now" button to no avail. Please advise.

Comment: If you can't get it via http you can get it via ftp or bittorrent... Ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't need donation to get downloaed.

Are you sure you are not downloading from any scam site? Also Ubuntu site doesn't have and `Download` button. It says `Get ubuntu 12.10` or `Get ubuntu 12.04`

You can download from here - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

If you want to get 13.04 beta (which is going to release this month)

Follow this link - http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/